# Eclipse can't start anymore

Tags: java, eclipse

when I click on eclipse it says a jre or jdk must be available in order to run eclipse. etc

how do I fix this?

thanks you

Comment: Just to make sure: is JDK installed on your machine? Did you perhaps update it recently which could change its path?

Answer (score 0):

David,

After installed JDK in your machine then configure the PATH, CLASS_PATH and JAVA_HOME variables in the Environment variable then Eclipse will open without any issues.

Comment: You should only need `java` on your `PATH`, the rest should be automatic.